# Power button on menu bar goes red regularly

Tags: unity, power-management

I've upgraded to 13.10

In previous versions, the power button in the menu bar would go red after an upgrade that needed a restart to complete.

Now the power button goes red after running for a couple of hours or so.  When it does, the reset option disappears from the menu (although reset is a clickable option from the shut down selection).  Also, there is no message when hovering the mouse over the button as there was previously.

I have been unable to find any information on what this might mean - and it does not seem mean much as the computer runs along fine.

When I do reset, however, the button is white again for a few hours.

Comment: Does `Online Accounts…` appear in the menu when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I had this after I activated Google verification service - Ubuntu required me to re-authenticate with Google. I guess the red icon means "something needs to be corrected" but it's not exactly clear on what when it happens.

@Dobev is right - look for "Account Options" under the "System Settings" menuitem.

After re-authenticating, icon returned to white.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was facebook.  I had to go into System Settings > Online Accounts > Facebook and authorize facebook again.

This really could be a little more intuitive than just making the icon turn red.